# Rails Action Mailer with deliver_later on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rails-activejob

I have my production app running on `AWS` but am having issues with the active job - `deliver_later` on certain mailers.  I am successfully sending all emails with `deliver_later` in development but there is something different in production.  Certain mailers work with `deliver_later` but not my welcome mailer (welcomes new users).  So I have to set `deliver_now` on this welcome mailer to have it actually send the email.

```
//doesn't work, email is not sent
UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver_later
//works
UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver_now
```

The log file from the server show this and nothing more when I use `deliver_later`:

> [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID:
>   d7114-464e-4a90-9721-126650) to Async(mailers) with arguments:
>   "UserMailer", "welcome_email", "deliver_now", #>

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deliver_now` Delivers an email at a time.

If you use `deliver_later` you have to use ActiveJob runner like `Sidekiq` you can see this [`gist Sending emails with ActionMailer and Sidekiq`](https://gist.github.com/maxivak/690e6c353f65a86a4af9) also see this for basic [`Sidekiq`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#action-mailer) email sent.

Enqueues the email to be delivered through Active Job. When the job runs it will send the email using `deliver_now`.

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver_later(wait: 1.hour)
```

[`method-i-deliver_later`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_later)

Basically, `deliver_later` is asynchronous. When you use this method, the email is not sent at the moment, but rather is pushed into a job's queue. If the job is not running, the email will not be sent. `deliver_now` will send the email at the moment, no matter what is the job's state. [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_later) you can see the documentation for delivery methods.

Answer (score 1):

#### What ActiveJob backend are you using?

- ActiveJob to provide asynchronous execution but does not provide asynchronicity itself.

You need to use some asynchronous backend like `sidekiq`, `delayed_job` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't set the time and rails picking up default time. and in log file also it shows that the deliver_later method is not being called yet.

Try using:

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver_later(wait: 1.minute)
```

Then check the log after one min.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using delayed_job, you have to run `rake jobs:work`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoGPaWEasxs